# regular expression conditional problems in C#

Tags: c#, xml, regex, xpath, xml-parsing

I have some content nested in span tags. Some of them have details I need to pull, and some do not. I can't figure out how to check for two options and pull the proper data. These groups repeat. For example:

```
<span name="foo">
    <span name="bar">
        Missing Data
    </span>
</span>
<span name="foo">
    <span name="bar">
        <span name="detail1">first detail</span>
        <span name="detail2">second detail</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I have to capture the details individually if they are there, otherwise I need to set those values to null in the strings in my program when looping through the matchcollection so my code needs to set strDetail1 and strDetail2 to "" or the values "first detail" and "second detail" if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using XPath to parse values. For parsing xml structure this will be more reliable than Regex.

```
var xml = @"
    <root>
    <span name=""foo"">
        <span name=""bar"">
            Missing Data
        </span>
    </span>
    <span name=""foo"">
        <span name=""bar"">
            <span name=""detail1"">first detail</span>
            <span name=""detail2"">second detail</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    </root>
";

var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var details = document.XPathSelectElements("//span[@name='foo']/span[@name='bar']/span[starts-with(@name,'detail')]")
    .Select(arg => arg.Value)
    .ToList();
```

or LINQ-to-XML

```
var details = document
    .Descendants("span").Where(arg => arg.Attribute("name").Value == "foo")
    .Elements("span").Where(arg => arg.Attribute("name").Value == "bar")
    .Elements("span").Where(arg => arg.Attribute("name").Value.StartsWith("detail"))
    .Select(arg => arg.Value)
    .ToList();
```

**[Edit]** I might misunderstand the question. Seems like you also want to replace or fill some values. You can do this with above-mentioned approach as long as you have `XDocument`. For example this code will clear values of the `detail1` and `detail2` elements:

```
var detailNodes = document.XPathSelectElements("//span[@name='foo']/span[@name='bar']/span[starts-with(@name,'detail')]")
    .ToList();

detailNodes[0].Value = string.Empty;
detailNodes[1].Value = string.Empty;

var newXml = document.ToString();
```

**[Edit]**

How to add an element:

```
var elementsWithMissingDetals = document
    .XPathSelectElements("//span[@name='foo']/span[@name='bar' and count(*)=0]")
    .ToList();

foreach (var elementsWithMissingDetal in elementsWithMissingDetals)
{
    elementsWithMissingDetal.Add(
        new XElement("span", "first detail", new XAttribute("name", "detail1")));
    elementsWithMissingDetal.Add(
        new XElement("span", "second detail", new XAttribute("name", "detail2")));
}

var newXml = document.ToString();
```

Comment: +1 - The sample code doesn't solve his entire problem (trying to grab all such values in a loop), but this example points the OP in the right direction.  Use XML tools for XML, and regex only for custom text, where you don't already have a standard format built around it.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham - Typo. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Interesting. I do like how this is heading. @Merlyn Morgan-Graham is right though, it's not totally answered. How do I account for that first one where there is "Missing Data" in it. I need the detail info for that one to be created with blank values. I've been chasing this regex very far down the rabbit hole. This is a zoomed in simplified example. I'm looping over repeating records pulling various bits out which I can convert from regex to linq-to-xml just fine I suppose, but I don't know what to do when I hit those odd ones that don't have the details.

Comment: @Twisted - you can equally loop over XML elements, and update them if needed. Will add example of adding an element in a minute.

Comment: Saw your latest edit. Yes I need to fill some values. Can you show me how to fill it if it isn't there?

Comment: LOL, you're beating me to the questions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Alex Aza thanks. I started converting my regex to this linq-to-xml technique and I hit a snag. This is html, not xml and there seems to be an issue when it hits some javascript. It hits :document.write('<img src="'+imgServer+'images/global/misc/spacer.gif" alt="" border="0" height="'+height+'" width="'+width+'">'); and throws an error saying the img tag does not match the end tag of 'script'.

Comment: Oh, it's throwing the error on the var document = XDocument.Parse(objUTF8.GetString(reqHTML));

Comment: hmm... I would need to get the html source to figure it out. As a workaround, you might want to get a fragment of your html as an input to `XDocument`.

Comment: I was actually thinking of regexing out the script content.

Comment: @Twisted - yep, this is the option.

Comment: I'll be doing that tomorrow, I've thoroughly fried my brain on regex today. Thanks again for the help.